# AHK for Warcraft (Not MultiBox) 2 Buttons - not simultaneous

Tags: button

I am not good at coding at all.  I want to use AHK to continually click key 1 when pressed and continually click key 2 when pressed.  I do not want them to auto click at the same time, I want them to only go when that key is clicked.

The script I am using is as follows works fine for one key, but I cannot figure out how to add a second key.

```
#IfWinActive, World of Warcraft
$1::
While GetKeyState("1","p"){
Send,1
sleep 70
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code

```
#IfWinActive, World of Warcraft

$1::
While GetKeyState("1","p"){
Send,1
sleep 70
}

$2::
While GetKeyState("2","p"){
Send,2
sleep 70
}
```